# Get AssetManager without context

Tags: android, android-assets, android-context

Is it possible to access the AssetManager without a Context? I've seen other people's solution is to extend Application, and save the Context in onCreate(), and create a static getter to return the Context. I feel this is really sloppy, and breaks encapsulation, since you've now given access to everything in your Context to your entire App. I suppose I could reduce it to saving just the AssetManager, but it's still a very hacky fix.

I know you can get access to Resources without a Context by calling something like

```
Resources.getSystem().getString()
```

However, accessing the AssetManager by

```
Resources.getSystem().getAssets()
```

Only grants you access to some built in assets, not what's actually in your assets folder.

Am I stuck with the hacky Application subclass, or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: why do you think saving the application context is sloppy? you can put it within the same class, and call getInstance() just like any other singleton...

Answer (score 0):

What do you need assets for? Just to open file(s)? It is possible to access resource files without Context by using [getResourceAsStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) method but they must be placed in the same folder as java source file.

Comment: Ahh, I see. The reason I'm using Assets is because I'm developing a Game Engine, and the idea is to drop the config files (all of the game's content) into the assets folder, keeping the engine and the content separate. The reason to use assets/ over res/ is because assets allows folders. The game engine is fairly complex, so having all the content stored in a single folder is not feasible.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to keep the Android specific OS calls extracted to the top level, so that I can potentially easily port the engine to any OS that has a JVM, which is why I can't pass the context around as parameters.